# Prevent opening Excel workbook saved in specific location

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to prevent users other than authorized users from opening a workbook if it's being opened from the location that the workbook is saved. What I want is for the user to copy the workbook to another location and then open it. I have used the code below for Access databases, but I am not sure how to adapt it for Excel. Can someone help?

```
Option Compare Database
Private Function AutoExec()
 ' Use Macro to run code and use the AutoExec() name
    If VBA.InStr(1, CurrentDb.Name, "G:\") _
    Or VBA.InStr(1, CurrentDb.Name, "\\NetWorkLocation\") Then

        Select Case VBA.StrConv(VBA.Environ("username"), vbLowerCase)
        Case "username1", "username2", "username3"

        Case Else
            VBA.MsgBox "Copy and paste this database to your desktop." _
                & vbCrLf & "You may not open it from this location."
         DoCmd.CloseDatabase
        End Select

    End If

 End Function
```

Comment: for starters, this won't ever evaluate properly if you always `vbLowerCase` the username but then compare against usernames starting with an uppercase letter, `Username1, ... ` :p

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I replaced the actual usernames when I pasted the code and used uppercases for the dummy usernames out of habit.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was just a little oversight. This isn't a big deal to convert. I'm working on it now but someone else may well beat me to it lol

Comment: You have a small typo in your message box - "spreadsheet" is misspelled "database".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the completed code and I have confirmed that it works.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

If VBA.InStr(1, Application.Workbook.Path, "G:\") > 0 _
Or VBA.InStr(1, Application.Workbook.Path, "\\NetWorkLocation\") > 0 Then

   Select Case VBA.StrConv(VBA.Environ("username"), vbLowerCase)
   Case "username1", "username2", "username3"

   Case Else
       VBA.MsgBox "Copy and paste this workbook to your desktop." _
            & vbCrLf & "You may not open it from this location."
   ActiveWorkbook.Close 

   End Select

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you drop this into the [`ThisWorkbook` module of the workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44) you want to limit access to, it should work.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If InStr(ThisWorkbook.path, "G:\") > 0 _
    Or InStr(ThisWorkbook.path, "\\NetWorkLocation\") > 0 Then

        Select Case LCase(Environ("username"))
        Case "username1", "username2", "username3"

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Copy and paste this spreadsheet to your desktop." & _
                vbCrLf & "You may not open it from this location."

            ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        End Select

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the code to the `ThisWorkbook` module and changed the username to someone else. After saving, closing, and then re-opening the workbook, nothing happens. The code doesn't seem to be running. I have the code pasted almost verbatim from how it is above. Thoughts?

Comment: @JosephD it might have been that I left out the `> 0` evaluation following `InStr()` ?

Comment: This should be called by the Workbook_Open event.  Change "Auto_Open" to "Workbook_Open".

Comment: Interesting, now that works. I see that auto_open only exists for compatiblity reasons but can you help me understand why it didnt work in this case, @FrankBall

Comment: The code runs, but I get a compile error in the `ThisWorkbook` module. The error indicates that there is incompatible code with the version, platform, or architecture of the application. I am using Excel 2010 to run the workbook if that helps.

Comment: Ah hm I can't really replicate that on my machine - the only "unusual" code would be the `Environ("username")` bit... could you try manually running the sub with a bunch of [breakpoints](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm) to see where it breaks?

Comment: @JosephD maybe it was the little `$` I used to designate that `LCase` was for a string? I'm not sure

Comment: I updated the code with what you changed and now it's not doing anything. I am not getting any compile errors, but it's also not running on workbook open.

Comment: Yeah, that's been my experience with coding in general. I appreciate you helping me with this though.

Comment: @FrankBall any ideas?

Comment: I added an update to the code. I think there's an issue with the username identification and comparison part. Thoughts?

Comment: @JosephD I’be never used `Application.Workbook` before, so I’m really not sure what it references

Comment: From what I have read, there isn't too much of a difference in the two references as long as you are only working with one workbook. I am not sure why the `ThisWorkbook` reference wasn't working for me, but I am not getting a compile error anymore and the code works as intended. Thanks again for your help. You got me 90% of the way there and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

ThisWorkbook.Path returns "G:", not "G:\" when the file is saved at the root of "G:".  Drop the "\" and you'll be golden.

FYI - I debugged this by putting the code into it's own function to make it easier to debug (didn't have to keep opening and closing the file to call the function), and then stepped through that function.  The first "If" statement failed and the check for the user never happened, So I added a Watch to ThisWorkbook.Path and saw that it was returning "G:" and not G:\".  Here's JosephD's function with the correction:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

If VBA.InStr(1, Application.Workbook.Path, "G:") > 0 _
Or VBA.InStr(1, Application.Workbook.Path, "\\NetWorkLocation\") > 0 Then

   Select Case VBA.StrConv(VBA.Environ("username"), vbLowerCase)
   Case "username1", "username2", "username3"

   Case Else
       VBA.MsgBox "Copy and paste this workbook to your desktop." _
            & vbCrLf & "You may not open it from this location."
   ActiveWorkbook.Close 

   End Select

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. The other code that I posted works with the `Application.Workbook. Path` code as intended. Did you go back to the `ThisWorkbook` reference?